# Error: Reference to undefined global `Num'

Tags: ocaml, bignum

I'm trying to use the `Num` module in OCaml (bignums and big fractions). Some things seem to be working, while others seem not to, and I'm not able to generate a single, complete example. For instance:

```
# Num.Int(234);;
- : Num.num = Num.Int 234
# Num.mult_num;;
Characters -1--1:
  Num.mult_num;;
Error: Reference to undefined global `Num'
```

May I ask for a simple example of multiplying two bignums?

The reference for `Num` is [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Num.html).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the toplevel is already launched, you can dynamically load the library:

```
# #load "nums.cma";;
# Num.mult_num;;
- : Num.num -> Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
```

Another possibility (which will work for all third party libraries and will manage paths and dependencies for you) is to use `ocamlfind`.  For this, issue

```
#use "topfind";;
```

(or better put it in your `~/.ocamlinit` file).  To load a library, just do

```
# #require "num";;
/usr/lib/ocaml/nums.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num-top: added to search path
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num-top/num_top.cma: loaded
/home/user/.opam/system/lib/num: added to search path
```

(If `ocamlfind` — hence `topfind` — is not available, install it using [opam](http://opam.ocaml.org/).)

Here is an example of multiplication:

```
# Num.(num_of_int 30 */ num_of_int 1234);;
- : Num.num = Num.Int 37020
```

The construction `Num.(e)` is a shorthand for `let open Num in e` and makes possible to use the `Num` functions without prefix in `e`.  Here is a definition of the factorial:

```
# let rec fac n =
    let open Num in
    if n =/ Int 0 then Int 1 else n */ fac (n -/  Int 1);;
val fac : Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
```

You can try it with

```
# fac Num.(Int 100);;
- : Num.num = Num.Big_int <abstr>
```

If you used `#require`, it installs a pretty printer for `Num` values so the previous interaction looks like:

```
# fac Num.(Int 100);;
- : Num.num =
<num 93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000>
```

which is much easier to read!

Comment: You taught me tons of ocaml in a single reply! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The `Num` module is provided by a library which is not linked by default. You need to pass the library on the linker or toplevel command line. You can use types (e.g. `Num.num`) and constructors (e.g. `Num.Int`) from the module, because they only require static (compile-time) information, but using variables (including functions, e.g. `Num.mult_num`) require dynamic information (code), which must be linked in explicitly.

For toplevel use:

```
$ ocaml nums.cma
        OCaml version 4.01.0

# Num.mult_num;;
- : Num.num -> Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
#
```

To compile and link a program:

```
ocamlc -o myprogram.byte myfile.ml nums.cma
ocamlopt -o myprogram.native myfile.ml nums.cmxa
```

The name of the library containing the module is provided at the beginning of the [chapter about the library in the Ocaml reference manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libnum.html). For many of these, the name of the library is the same as the name of the sole module it contains, but that's a convention, not an obligation. For libraries like `nums` that contain multiple modules, you need to look up the name of the library.

Answer (score 0):

`Num` is an independent library (not part of the standard library), that must be required before it is used in the toplevel.

```
$ ocaml nums.cma

# Num.mult_num;;
- : Num.num -> Num.num -> Num.num = <fun>
```